# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of $\lim_{x\to 2}\sqrt{2x-3}=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim_{x\to 2}\sqrt{2x-3}=1$. Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. We want to find 
a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-2|<\delta$ then $|\sqrt{2x-3}-1|<\epsilon$.
Let's find $\delta$.

First notice that $f(x)=\sqrt{2x-3}$ is defined for $x\ge \dfrac{3}{2}$. So the distance from $2$ to $\dfrac{3}{2}$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Second notice that $|f(x)-1|=|\sqrt{2x-3}-1|=\dfrac{2|x-2|}{\sqrt{2x-3}+1}$

Third we have that $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x-3}+1}\leq 1$ because $\sqrt{2x-3}+1\ge 1$

Let $\;\delta:=\inf\left(\cfrac12,\cfrac\epsilon2\right)\;$. If $\;0<|x-2|<\delta\;$
then $$|f(x)-1|=\dfrac{2|x-2|}{\sqrt{2x-3}+1}<\epsilon$$

Is my work correct? and is there any other simpler way to prove it ? thank you for your help!

Comment: No, you don't want "to choose" $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t. etc.: you **must prove the existence** of such a $\;\delta>0\;$ for *any* given $\;\epsilon>0\;$ .

Comment: ok I will edit my sentence

Comment: As this is a very basic exercise perhaps in "Third, we have that..."  you should explain a little more why is that true. In general, I think your work is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

Prove  using $\epsilon-\delta$, that

$$\lim_{x\to 2}(2x-3)=1$$

and then take root.

Comment: It's not so simple. In this way, you should also prove that $\lim_{x\to c}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{c}$, which is not apparently easier then the OP's question. Moreover, you should prove that the limit of the composition of these two functions--- $(x\mapsto\sqrt{x})\circ (x\mapsto 2x-3)$, is $\sqrt{2x-3}\Bigg|_{x=2}$, by proving the limit law of composition.